# Optimize image using script when uploading

Tags: php, image, file-upload, optimization

Am try upload image to server while uploading i need the image to be optimized

- i need script to optimized
- types of file(jpeg,png,gif)

i found many online tool like http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/ but i need script its possible to use script

`<input name="file" type="file" id="ufile"  />` this the input method am using

- how to optimize image and save to custom folder

Upload script

```
<form action="for.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
         <input name="file" type="file" id="ufile" size="50" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? May be you should post your php code that is not working, otherwise your question will turn a downvote fest because of unclear.

Comment: tryed with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043369/image-optimization

Comment: I mean where is your code? What have you tried? Paste it into your question. Personally i dont follow reference links in questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this function am using this in my program it works fine

```
<?php
############ Configuration ##############
$thumb_square_size      = 200; //Thumbnails will be cropped to 200x200 pixels
$max_image_size         = 5000; //Maximum image size (height and width)
$thumb_prefix           = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix
$destination_folder     = 'uploads/'; //upload directory ends with / (slash)
$jpeg_quality           = 90; //jpeg quality
##########################################

//continue only if $_POST is set and it is a Ajax request
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

// check $_FILES['ImageFile'] not empty
if(!isset($_FILES['image_file']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']    ['tmp_name'])){
        die('Image file is Missing!'); // output error when above checks     fail.
}

//uploaded file info we need to proceed
$image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name']; //file name
$image_size = $_FILES['image_file']['size']; //file size
$image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp

$image_size_info    = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size

if($image_size_info){
    $image_width        = $image_size_info[0]; //image width
    $image_height       = $image_size_info[1]; //image height
    $image_type         = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
}else{
    die("Make sure image file is valid!");
}

//switch statement below checks allowed image type 
//as well as creates new image from given file 
switch($image_type){
    case 'image/png':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp); break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp); break;           
    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
        $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp); break;
    default:
        $image_res = false;
}

if($image_res){
    //Get file extension and name to construct new file name 
    $image_info = pathinfo($image_name);
    $image_extension = strtolower($image_info["extension"]); //image extension
    $image_name_only = strtolower($image_info["filename"]);//file name only, no     extension

    //create a random name for new image (Eg: fileName_293749.jpg) ;
    $new_file_name = $image_name_only. '_' .  rand(0, 9999999999) . '.' .     $image_extension;

    //folder path to save resized images and thumbnails
    $thumb_save_folder  = $destination_folder . $thumb_prefix .     $new_file_name; 
    $image_save_folder  = $destination_folder . $new_file_name;

    //call normal_resize_image() function to proportionally resize image
    if(normal_resize_image($image_res, $image_save_folder, $image_type,     $max_image_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality))
    {
        //call crop_image_square() function to create square thumbnails
        if(!crop_image_square($image_res, $thumb_save_folder, $image_type,     $thumb_square_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality))
        {
            die('Error Creating thumbnail');
        }

        /* We have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
        We can now output image to user's browser or store information in     the database*/
        echo '<div align="center">';
        echo '<img src="uploads/'.$thumb_prefix . $new_file_name.'"     alt="Thumbnail">';
        echo '<br />';
        echo '<img src="uploads/'. $new_file_name.'" alt="Resized Image">';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    imagedestroy($image_res); //freeup memory
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the function 'normal_resize_image' defined ?